# Knight Artorias in Dark Souls

Tags: dark-souls

I've had a theory about the Soul's series and it's a bit of a long shot but I'm not going to get into that. What I wanted to know is: Are there any lore connections to Knight Artorias in vanilla Dark Souls? I can't come up with any and just want to see if anybody may know of some. Just to clarify, the DLC does NOT count for this question.

Comment: Are you speaking exclusively within Dark Souls 1?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're asking... Artorias first appeared in the DLC, but, seeing as the DLC takes place in the past, he would have a place in the present day lore. Can you clarify at all?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed in chester's dialogue that he refers to Artorias "Did you happen across Knight Artorias?
The legendary Abysswalker, from the old tales.
…Well, if you haven't, it's just as well…
He's a colourless sort, if you ask me.
Mwah hah hah!" as being in the past. My theory involves the time inconsistencies and how Artorias was (as far as I can tell) never mentioned in vanilla Dark Souls. I don't want to get into all that though, I just need to see if he was actually mentioned anywhere in the lore pre-DLC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are multiple references to Knight Artorias in DkS 1 outside of the DLC.

- He was one of the 4 Chosen Knights under Gwyn.
- The Great Grey Wolf Sif was his companion, and he weilds Artorias' Sword.
- Artorias is mentioned as "the one who made a Covenant with Kaathe, to walk within the Abyss" (not a direct quote). This ring; **Covenant of Artorias** drops from Sif, and allows you to enter the abyss to fight the Four Kings.
- The Wolf Ring belonged to Artorias.

If you're looking for *direct quotes containing the name Artorias* there are a few:

- **Wolf Ring:** "One of the special rings granted to the four knights of Gwyn. The wolf ring belongs to Artorias the Abysswalker. Artorias had an unbendable will of steel, and was unmatched with a greatsword."
- **Covenant of Artorias**: "This ring symbolizes Knight Artorias' covenant with the beasts of the Abyss. Its wearer, like Artorias himself, can traverse the abyss."

---

**Graveyard Edit:** (Can't believe I left this out) The swords forged from the Soul of Sif also reference Artorias.

- **Greatsword of Artorias:** "Sword born from the soul of the great grey wolf Sif, guardian of the grave of the Abysswalker Knight Artorias. Sir Artorias hunted the Darkwraiths, and his sword strikes harder against dark servants."
- **Cursed Greatsword of Artorias:** "Sword born from the soul of the great grey wolf Sif, guardian of the grave of the Abysswalker Knight Artorias. The sword can damage ghosts, as it was cursed when Artorias joined a covenant with the creatures of the Abyss."

Comment: I was looking for more direct lore but this works for me. Back to the drawing board! And thank you lol